# "The reason why X is because" or "The reason why X is that"

Tags: sentence-choice

So, there's a group called One sentence startup pitches in Facebook and I posted the following sentence there.

> A startup/university/research institution that would prove that the reason why no one has traveled from future to the present is ***because*** climate change destroyed the planet before anyone could invent the time machine.

A native speaker corrected me and told me that it should be:

> A startup/university/research institution that would prove that the reason why no one has traveled from future to the present is ***that*** climate change destroyed the planet before anyone could invent the time machine.

I am sort of naturally skeptical. So I thought I should post here to confirm.

Comment: You have touched down two constructions which was objected by grammarians since ages. Generally their objection is based on the theory that they are redundant. But still, the day to day usage shows that it is not unnatural or anything that doesn't go along well with anyone other than uneducated people. Both of you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correction is appropriate.

However, you could also keep **because** if you remove **the reason why** and **is**:

> A startup/university/research institution that would prove that no one has traveled from future to the present because climate change destroyed the planet before anyone could invent the time machine.